# Using a client's IP to get content

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I'm a bit embarrassed here because I am trying to get content remotely, by using the client's browser and not the server. But I have specifications which make it look impossible to me, I literally spent all day on it with no success.

1. The data I need to fetch is on a distant server.
2. I don't own this server (I can't do any modification to it).
3. It's a string, and I need to get it and pass it to PHP.
4. It **must** be the client's (user browsing the website) browser that actually gets the data (it needs to be it's IP, and not the servers).

And, with the cross-domain policy I don't seem to be able to get around it. I already knew about it, still tried a simple Ajax query, which failed. Then I though 'why not use iFrames', but the same limitation seems to apply to them too. I then read about using YQL (http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) but I noticed the server I was trying to reach blocked YQL's user-agent making it impossible to use this technique.

So, that's all I could think about or find. But I can't believe it's not possible to achieve such a thing, that doesn't even look hard...

Oh, and my Javascript knowledge is very basic, this mustn't help either.

Comment: Have you considered just launching a new browser window to fetch the string and ask the user to cut and paste it back into his browser? Also, client IP addresses aren't guanranteed to be unique.  Two are more PCs behind the same NAT or corporate firewall are going to have the same IP to an external site.   Why is it that the server authenticates based on IP?

Comment: It's not to authenticate the users I need their IP to be used, it's just because the data returned by the server will not be relevant otherwise. For what I am trying to do. And the string is actually XML so they wouldn't even see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one reason that the same-origin policy exists. You're trying to have your webpage access data on a different server, without the user knowing, and without having "permission" from the other server to do so.

Without establishing a two-way trust system (ie modifying the 'other' server), I believe this is not possible.

Even with new xhr and crossdomain support, two-way trust is still required for the communication to work.

You could consider a fat-client approach, or try @selbie suggestion and require manual user interaction.

Comment: Yes, but why could I get it in PHP or any other language really but not using Ajax ? I don't understand this part. I could use a simple file_get_contents() or browse to the URL using my browser or any HTTP request "maker" such as cURL. It's the exact same thing. The administrator of the other server doesn't know I'm going to visit his site. Still, if it's online he must think someone will. Nothing dodgy.

Comment: And what do you mean by "consider fat-client approach" ?

Comment: PHP is server side code. it' doesn't execute in the browser. Web browsers enforce the same-origin-policy. The difference in your other two approaches is: 1) with PHP, it's the server doing the request, thus the request has your server IP address (the problem you are trying to address) 2) The user manually wanted to visit the other server, which means the user implicitly trusts that other server.

Comment: And a "fat client" is an executable that you run locally, that doesn't have the same restrictions as a web application/thin client.

Comment: Yes, @alan, I gathered that now. But I just don't see the point.

Comment: @BenCoriou There might be a way to do it, I'm certainly not the most elite web dev out there, but I believe the other server needs to be setup in a way to allow you to make crossdomain calls with all approaches. The fat-client suggestion was just a possible workaround. If you can get users to download an app, then it can do what you want, but this may not be feasible given your spec.

Comment: I have considered this option of course. It would be very convinient and would also be finished by now. And my specs would allow such a scenario it's just that, these days, it's really hard to make someone download and run an an application. Especially a random application which will run in the background (in my case). I don't think I would download it myself.

Comment: I'll tell you more about what I am actually trying to do. The content I am trying to access is an XML sheet on a remote server. So far, no biggy. The thing is, it will block servers from connecting to it (I don't know how it detects them so well, probably hostname or something). This is why I would like to use the users' IP addresses because from the server it wouldn't deliver the content. I have tried with several servers and several IP addresses, it always flags the connection as a connection from a server and not some user. Nothing to do with user-agent or referrer either. I'm really stuck

Comment: @Ben, the reason why you can do it on the server and not on the client is because when the client makes requests, it does so with the full authority of the user.  Any HTTP authorisation or cookies would be transmitted along with the request, so a third-party website could perform any action on your behalf for any website you happened to be logged into at the same time.  This would obviously be a gaping security hole big enough to drive a bus through.

Comment: oh @Jim, I was wondering why it could be a security flow. I see now. Stealing cookies is big enough. Thank you for lighting my candle. What, it's a French saying, don't laugh !

Comment: Not heard that one before, but it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

```
The same origin policy prevents document or script loaded from one 
origin from getting or setting properties of a document from a different
origin.
```

-- From http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/same-origin.html

Now if you wish to do some hackery to get it... [visit this site](http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=Introduction_to_Cross-Domain_Ajax)

*Note: I have never tried any of the methods on the aforementioned site and cannot guarantee their success*

Comment: the 2nd link also requires the other server to respond with javascript (similar to JSONP).

Comment: Already tried this. Basically using YQL as a proxy and fetching JSON result. Yahoo!'s user-agent is blocked. No getting around that.

Answer (score -1):

I can only see a really ugly solution: iFrames. [This article](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes) contains some good informations to start with.

Comment: I have read this article, but I don't know if it can actually do what I need to do. I have tried accessing the data in the iFrame, but the cross-domain policy also blocks me to do so.

Comment: Is this really a solution? The hosted iframe from the "other" server needs to properly communicate with the iframe from the local server.

Comment: And yeah, remember I can't change anything whatsoever on the distant server. It will basically return a XML sheet with the informations I need. And there's no way I can get the informations I am after elsewhere than this distant server.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it with flash application:
[flash with a crossdomain.xml file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html) (won't help though since you don't control the other server)

On new browsers there is [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/) - requires Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set on the server side.

You can also try to use [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) (but I think that won't work since you don't own the other server).

I think you need to bite the bullet and find some other way to get the content (on the server side for example).

Comment: For crossdomain.xml and flash, I'm pretty sure the other server needs a corresponding crossdomain.xml file. CORS also requires the other server to support cross domain calls.

Comment: Yes, CORS was already an option I considered but in my case it wouldn't work. Same for Flash. Thank you for input though !!